# partial submission on hacker rank

Tags: c

why is my code http://ideone.com/zm6hP7  not satisfying all test cases in the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/opc-a/challenges/infinite-series  ?
I have downloaded unsatisfied test cases and still can't find any problem in my code....can somebody tell me what the problem is???

```
#include<stdio.h>`
#define m 1000000007
int main()
{
long long int t;
scanf("%lld",&t);
for(long long int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    long long int l,r;
    scanf("%lld %lld",&l,&r);
    long long int x,y;
    if(l%2==0)
        x=(((l/2)%m)*((l-1)%m))%m;
    else
        x=((l%m)*(((l-1)/2)%m))%m;
    if(r%2==0)
        y=(((r/2)%m)*((r+1)%m))%m;
    else
        y=((r%m)*(((r+1)/2)%m))%m;
    printf("%lld\n",y-x);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely mistake is that `y-x` is negative when y(mod m) < x(mod m). This can be corrected by adding this at the end, before the `printf()` statement:

```
if(y-x < 0)
{
    y += m;
}
```

Comment: thanks GoodDeeds.....that was exactly the problem